# MySql GROUP BY timestamp interval where interval has passed

Tags: mysql, group-by, timestamp

Is it possible to select only the records where the interval has passed?

For e.g. in a select with group by for a table like this:
`TABLE (timestamp(timestamp), name(VARCHAR))`

```
timestamp            name  
-------------------  ----  
2010-11-16 10:30:01  John  
2010-11-16 10:30:02  John  
2010-11-16 10:30:03  John  
2010-11-16 10:30:31  John  
2010-11-16 10:30:32  John  
2010-11-16 10:30:33  John
```

The query:

```
SELECT max(timestamp), name, count(name) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 30, name
```

The result:

```
timestamp            name       count(name)  
    -------------------  ----   -----------
    2010-11-16 10:30:03  John     3 
    2010-11-16 10:30:33  John     3
```

This will group by records from:

`hour:minute:00 to hour:minute:29` 
and from: 
`hour:minute:30 to hour:minute:59`

If I make the query at `10:30:55`, I want to get only the records from the previous interval `10:30:00` to `10:30:29` (and older) without the records added between `10:30:30` to `10:30:59`.

In other words if I query inside some interval wait for it to pass before showing the records.
Note the query might not be made always at the same second (`10:30:55`) it might be `10:30:51` or anything else.

So the result with the clause should be:

```
        timestamp            name       count(name)  
        -------------------  ----   -----------
        2010-11-16 10:30:03  John     3
```

If it is made at `2010-11-16 10:30:55` for example.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Believe you want `WHERE HOUR(...) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 11`

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate. I need 30 seconds intervals and if the interval has not passed don't show the records. I don't know when the query will be made if it would be at `hour:minute:11` or another second `hour:minute:28`. How can I dynamically give the interval in the where clause?

Comment: MCVE mean sample data, current and expected output. Right now we only have one of those. Also help having the DDL so we can easily reproduce the test case

Comment: I added the example and the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4b58f/2)

```
SELECT max(timestamp), name, count(name) 
FROM table1
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 30 < 
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-11-16 10:30:55') DIV 30
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 30, name
;
```

I hard code the current date `'2010-11-16 10:30:55'` but you can use `NOW()` function instead

**OUTPUT**

```
|       max(timestamp) | name | count(name) |
|----------------------|------|-------------|
| 2010-11-16T10:30:03Z | John |           3 |
```

If you only want the last group then add

```
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 30 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I will have to do some more extensive testing to see if it misses any record or interval but right now seems to work perfectly. Thank you!